# Как называть человека сменившего имя, говоря о нем до смены имени?

Tags: ономастика

Предположим, что человек сменил имя в 2015 году. Я пишу о человеке в 2016 году и описываю событие 2014 года. Как по правилам русского языка нужно назвать человека в моем тексте — новым или старым именем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны разные варианты в зависимости от того, какое из имён более известно адресатам и о каких событиях идёт речь. Иногда есть смысл в дополнительных пояснениях.

> В 1970 году Кэт Стивенс (ныне известный под именем Юсуф Ислам) записал
>   такой-то альбом.

(под прежним именем, тоже не от рождения полученным, музыкант более известен, а каждому из двух имён соответствуют свои работы)

> В 2014 году писатель Иван Помидоров написал свои первые рассказы (до
>   2015 года он подписывался своим настоящим именем, Иван Петров).

(если писатель известен под псевдонимом, а речь идёт о его творчестве)

> В 2014 году известный вам Сергей (тогда его ещё звали Самвелом)
>   приехал в наш город.

Answer (score 2):

В исторических работах, которые мне попадались, чаще всего давали наиболее известное имя, при необходимости давая сноску на другие имена: Ленин (Ульянов) Сталин (Джугашвили), Чингисхан (Темучин). Однако если рассматриваемый период не выходил за рамки смены имени, то использовалось то имя, которое человек носил в то время.

Я в своих работах тоже придерживаюсь подобного принципа. Если я рассказываю о нынешнем президенте Таджикистана до 2007 г. - он Э. Ш. Рахмонов, если после -  Э. Рахмон, а если исследование затрагивает оба периода - то Э. Ш. Рахмонов, но в скобках даю сведения об имени после 2007 г.

Answer (score 1):

Таких правил нет и быть не может.
Выбирайте то, что считаете нужным, то, которое не вызовет непонимания у читателя. Обычно это наиболее известное из двух.
При необходимости - дайте оба имени.

*Вообще такие вопросы регулируются правилами не языка, а этикета. Но русской и вообще европейской традиции такая церемониальность совершенно не свойственна. Что-то отдаленно похожее есть только в азиатских культурах. В Японии это касается в основном членов императорской семьи, сам император может за время жизни несколько раз поменять имя (при том, что называть живого императора по имени вообще не принято), а после смерти приобрести еще одно, посмертное. И тут действительно важно не ошибиться при выборе такого имени-титула. В Китае **все** новорожденные получают первое, детское имя, которое потом, по достижении зрелости обязательно меняется, иногда не один раз. И тут тоже есть принципиальная необходимость назвать человека правильным именем.*

*В русской традиции ничего подобного нет.*

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать слово **урождённый**:

> ... *Новое-имя* (урождённый *Старое-имя*) ...

Хотя традиционно это слово используют для фамилий.